# using \def changes matrix alignment

Tags: latex, beamer, tikz

Because I was using `\alt<1-4>{1}{\textbf{1}}` a lot in my tikz matrices I decided to encode it in a `\def` as

```
\def\altBold<#1>#2{%
  \alt<#1>{#2}{\textbf{#2}}
}
```

but the alignment of matrix elements that use `\altBold` has now changed.

Could anybody please show me how I can fix this macro so that it has the same appearance as the verbose (and cluttering) alternative?

Many thanks.

Comment: This may be better answered on TeX & LaTex Stack Exchange.

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/692112/36296